# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined React.js

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

I am writing the following in my React code:

```
var React = require('react');
```

I followed the React setup from [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm). I installed all the things at /Desktop/reactApp/. 
The React code is being run from `/GitProjects/DjangoProjects/MyProj/MyApp/static/react/dashboard.js`. I keep on getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError`. Am I missing something?

Note: HTML file at `/GitProjects/DjangoProjects/MyProj/MyApp/templates/dashboard.html` is calling my dashboard.js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to include a file `dashboard.js` in HTML.

If this file contains code like `require('react');` then it means that you need to first compile it using a build tool that will actually find `react` and bundle it together with your own code.

In case of the tutorial you're linking, the build tool used is `webpack`. Your HTML should include the file generated by webpack (`index.js`, or whatever you have in `output` section of webpack config), rather than `dashboard.js` alone.

`webpack.config.js`

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',  # the main code of your app that require()s other files

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',  # the file you should be including in HTML
   },
```

Comment: Still getting that same error. Installed webpack. set the **entry** in webpack config to ./MyApp/static/MyApp/react/dashboard.js and **output** to ./MyApp/static/MyApp/bundles. Ran the command webpack. Successfully created the folder bundles. In my HTML I have, <script type="text/babel" src="{% static 'MyApp/react/dashboard.js' %}"></script> . Opening the browser and seeing the same error "require not defined".

Comment: why `<script type="text/babel">`? If you're using webpack, you should configure it to run Babel for you and output plain ES5 that you include as `text/javascript`. Also you shouldn't include `dashboard.js` in your HTML. Include the bundle instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Done!!! Actually I had messed up the directory structure of my project.